# 555-timer circuit supposed to give 50% duty cycle square wave doesn't

Tags: 555, generator, duty-cycle

I wanted to build a circuit that gives 50%-duty-cycle square wave. I built the circuit of figure 4.4.6 from [this link](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Oscillators/osc44.php) which is shown below:

[image]

I used the NE555 chip, and used a potentiometer instead of the resistor. The resulting waveform is shown below:

[image]

You can see that it's not a 50%-duty-cycle as expected.

What is the reason of that? Charging and discharging are done using the same resistor and capacitor, so on-time and off-time should be equal.

Comment: We can see the picture, but the link to the page where you got the picture seems to be missing.

Comment: Oh sorry. I added the link.

Comment: If you use the CMOS version instead of the ancient bipolar version, you will get very close to 50% duty cycle, provided you don't overload the output.

Comment: A common old trick is to just run the 555 at twice the frequency you really want and connect its output to a flip-flop connected as a divide-by-two. The output will be completely symmetric for all ordinary purposes.

Comment: Ditto that!  If it's important for the duty cycle to be as close as possible to 50%, then a divide-by-two stage will remove any asymmetry from the waveform.

Comment: Having the same problem but mine seems worse. A probe on pin two and pin three: https://imgur.com/a/Q6GdvG3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the 555 internal diagram you can see that the output you use is not symmetrical: the top side is a darlington, so it has (at least) two Vbe drops. The low side is a common emitter, so it can be saturated.

[image]

In short: the output low will be closer to ground than the output high will be to Vcc.

One way to compensate would be a low-valued resistor between the output and Vcc.

Comment: Aha, thanks. But can you please explain how connecting that resistor will compensate?

Comment: It will lower the voltage drop when the output is high. But the cost is a higher current when the output is low.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answer has anything to do with duty cycle.

Comment: @tcrosley Instead of the default 555 configuration, which uses the discharge pin and a pull-up resistor, the OP uses the output pin to drive the charge and discharge of the timing capacitor. He hoped this would lead to a (more) symmetrical waveform, but the drive of the output pin is not symmetrical: high is less high than low is low, hence the high part will take longer than the low part (as can be seen on the scope output).

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I've encountered a problem. The resistor becomes too hot during the operation of the circuit. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: What value do you use?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen 330 Ohm becomes too hot fast. 1 kOhm becomes too hot also but slower than 330 Ohm. 10 kOhm is slower but doesn't do the compensation.

Comment: 1k becomes too hot?? What is your supply voltage? (And what you do mean by 'too hot': to touch? Does it smoke?)

Answer (score 4):

The [Original Source](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/Oscillators/osc44.php) explains this.

Most 555 astable oscillator designs use two resistors and depend on Vcc.  This typically means a Duty cycle > 50%.

This design uses Vout, so the timing circuit acts as a load on the output, which can effect frequency and mark to space ratio.  An idiosyncrasy of the design.

Try [Adjust 555-Based Generator's Duty Cycle Without Affecting Frequency](http://electronicdesign.com/power/adjust-555-based-generators-duty-cycle-without-affecting-frequency) from Electronic Design.  They walk you through how to set up resistors and capacitor.

[image: 50% duty cycle 555]
Edit...

For completeness, I've included the formulas from Electronic Design and modified procedure.
$$p = \frac {R_2} {R_1}\ \ \ \ \ \ q = \frac {R_3} {R_1}$$
$$t_1 = R_1\ C\ (p+1)\times ln(2)\ \ [1]$$
$$t_2= R_1\ C\ \left ( {p + \frac {q}{q+1}} \right ) \times ln\left ( {\frac {q-2}{2q-1}} \right )\ \ [2]$$
For 50% Duty Cycle:
$$t_1 = t_2$$
$$R_1\ C\ (p+1)\times ln(2) = R_1\ C\ \left ( {p + \frac {q}{q+1}} \right ) \times ln\left ( {\frac {q-2}{2q-1}} \right ) \ \ [3]$$
$$f = \frac {1}{2 t_1}= \frac {0.7213}{R_1\ C\ (p+1)}\ \ [4]$$

The procedure is as follows:

1. Set the desired frequency and select a value for C.
2. Calculate R1 from Equation 4.
3. Pick a R3.
4. Calculate q.
5. Calculate the value of p from Equation 3.
6. Calculate R2 = pR1.

Comment: Thanks. But the link you provided is of the picture you put.

Comment: Fixed.  I initially checked it, but must of fooled it up along the way.

Answer (score 2):

The only sure-fire way I know of to get a *perfect* 50% duty cycle is to send the 555 output to a flip-flop of your choice. Make sure it is compatible with the 555's working voltage.
 Any pulse stream the 555 puts out is divided by 2, with a *perfect* 50% duty cycle. I would prefer that over several trim pots (which drift with temperature by as much as 200 ppm). The flip-flop also sharpens the rising and falling edge of the square wave.
 For 12 volt circuits you can use the CD4013, for 5 volt circuits you can use a 74HC74, which will work down to 3 volts. Do not use 74AC74, as its rise/fall time is so fast it may cause ringing in the outputs. By itself the 555 has its limits without adding a lot of parts.

Comment: According to the website the OP used for that design, it will work but many factors can make the duty-cycle other than 50%-50%. It would never be used in a production run where a 50% duty cycle had to be accurate and stable over time.

Answer (score 0):

According to the datasheet I found at: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf, page 11,

$$D=\frac{R_B}{R_A+2R_B}$$

where R_A is between pin 7 and +V_CC and R_B is between pins 6 and 7.  I don't see either resistor in your diagram.

Comment: That's an entirely different way of using the 555 as an astable. The OP's way is equally  valid, and simpler.

Answer (score -1):

To get a squarewave from a 555; - I run the 555 at some HIGHER frequency ...and feed it into a 74393 dual counter chip ...versatility and accuracy goes THROUGH the ROOF!!! http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls393-sp.pdf

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ls393-sp.pdf